# Oracle's 'CHECK' CONSTRAINT in 'CREATE TYPE nnn AS OBJECT' -clause

Tags: oracle10g

It seems that it is not possible to define the CHECK -constraint in the CREATE TYPE -clause. This is doable in the CREATE TABLE -clause. Wondering if I'm doing something wrong here, since it feels that it would be convenient to use it in TYPE -definitions and further refer it in the CREATE TABLE -part.

```
CREATE TYPE address_type AS OBJECT (
StreetAddress varchar2(200),
City        varchar2(50),
AddressType   varchar2(20)
constraint ckAddressType check (AddressType in ('HO address', 'Billing address', 'Other address'))
);
```

This produces an error

> "[Error] PLS-00103 (5: 3): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "CONSTRAINT" when expecting one of the following: := ) , ei tyhjä
>   oletus external character"

Comment: This is nowhere in the manual. Why do you think that should work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check constraint on a type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23954390/check-constraint-on-a-type)