# PLSQL: Add constraint in a sub-type

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have a situation dealing with inheritance in SQL3, where I need to have a check constraint in a sub-type without creating a table of that sub-type, consider the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE familycar_t AS OBJECT (
  make VARCHAR (10),
  model VARCHAR(10),
  year NUMBER (4),
  fuel_type VARCHAR (10)
) NOT FINAL;
    
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE sedan_t UNDER familycar_t (
  cylinder_Size  number(10)
);
    
CREATE TABLE familycar OF familycar_t (PRIMARY KEY (make,model));

INSERT INTO familycar SELECT sedan_t( 'Ford', 'Model-T', 1908, 'Petrol', 4 ) FROM DUAL;
INSERT INTO familycar SELECT familycar_t( 'Ford', 'Model-A', 1903, 'Petrol' ) FROM DUAL;
```

Is there a way to add a constraint on the `cylinder_Size` attribute of type `sedan_t` so it has to be greater than 2 for example?

Comment: You could create a custom constructor that added validations on `cylinder_size`.  And then add methods that allow you to modify `cylinder_size` and enforce the logic for updates.

Comment: This is a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23954390/check-constraint-on-a-type

Comment: I checked it before it didn't solve my issue @Markus

Comment: Is this more a theoretical question about types and constraints or are you looking for a pragmatic solution even if it doesn’t use types? And: Why do you use types here at all? Why don’t you store the type (sedan or family car) as a data column in a general table ‘car’? It’s important to know in order to help you finding a solution that fits. If it is more theoretical, then Justin’s approach should be your choice.

Comment: I have to use types here, and I figured that constraints wouldn't work here (the way it's defined) so I'm using a trigger instead and it works now as it has been answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71928313/sql-creating-a-trigger-before-subtype-insert) @Markus