# SQL: Creating a trigger before subtype insert

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So I'm dealing with a situation can be described as the following:
Basically, I have two types car and supercar

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CAR_T AS OBJECT (
  id VARCHAR (10),
  fuel_type VARCHAR (10)
) NOT FINAL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SUPERCAR_T UNDER CAR_T (
  number_cylinders  number(10)
);
```

When inserting a supercar into car:

```
INSERT INTO CAR VALUES(SUPERCAR_T(99, 'petrol', 12));
```

I'd like to check if the the number of cylinders is greater than 6 before inserting into CAR table WITHOUT CREATING A TABLE FOR SUPERCARS:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INSERT_SUPERCAR
    BEFORE INSERT ON CAR
    REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
    FOR EACH ROW

    BEGIN
        IF :NEW.number_cylinders < 6 THEN
                RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Not a supercar');
    END;
```

I always end up with the following error:

```
bad bind variable 'NEW.number_cylinders'
```

It appears that I cannot access the attribute of the subtype directly. My question is how to fix such an error, and is there a better way to do it using check constraint without creating a new table for supercars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`:NEW.OBJECT_VALUE` pseudo-column](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/OBJECT_VALUE-Pseudocolumn.html) and the [`TREAT` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TREAT.html) to cast the object to a `SUPERCAR_T` type and then check the `number_cylinders` attribute:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INSERT_SUPERCAR
  BEFORE INSERT ON CAR
  REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.OBJECT_VALUE IS OF (SUPERCAR_T)
      AND TREAT(:NEW.OBJECT_VALUE AS SUPERCAR_T).number_cylinders < 6
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Not a supercar');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
INSERT INTO CAR VALUES(SUPERCAR_T(99, 'petrol', 12));
```

Works but:

```sql
INSERT INTO CAR VALUES(SUPERCAR_T(99, 'petrol', 4));
```

Raises the exception:

> ```
> ORA-20001: Not a supercar
> ```

---

You could also use a `CHECK` constraint:

```sql
ALTER TABLE car ADD CONSTRAINT car__supercar_cylinders__chk CHECK (
  OBJECT_VALUE IS NOT OF (SUPERCAR_T)
  OR TREAT(OBJECT_VALUE AS SUPERCAR_T).number_cylinders >= 6
);
```

or

```sql
ALTER TABLE car ADD CONSTRAINT car__supercar_cylinders2__chk CHECK (
  TREAT(OBJECT_VALUE AS SUPERCAR_T).number_cylinders IS NULL
  OR TREAT(OBJECT_VALUE AS SUPERCAR_T).number_cylinders >= 6
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0fbd7086177f015588fd9df747a79c3a)*

Comment: Agree but I think you would also need an 'IS OF (type)' condition somewhere (either in WHEN clause or trigger body) to avoid an attempt to 'TREAT' car_t (or other instantiable subtypes) as supercar_t.

Comment: @Padders Apparently, yes, in the PL/SQL scope you do need the extra check. In the SQL scope its fine to do it without.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for pointing out the difference.

Comment: @MT0 Thanks that fixed my issue, really appreciate your answers even this demo example is inspired by one of your previous answers to a diff question. Anyways thanks for the help.